# Где лучше использовать Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, coredata

Я новичок в swift, мне стало интересно, в каких приложениях лучше использовать Core Data.
Я делаю приложения "todo list", нужно ли использовать базу данных или можно обойтись?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для хранения базы данных с самими запланированными делами (имею ввиду ваше приложение to-do), CoreData самое то. Вообще, принцип примерно такой: если данных много то храните их в CoreData (и/или в облаке), если данные маленькие, обычно это касается настроек приложения, то храните их в UserDefaults.

Еще, хорошая и простая альтернатива для CoreData, это Realm, но это отдельный фреймворк и ставится через POD. Но он реально стоит того, чтобы хотя бы попробовать.